# What does @$ mean in makefile?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, automatic-variable

What does @$ mean in the below make recipe ?

`@$(OBJCOPY) -S --set-section-flags .bss=alloc,contents -O binary $(BINARY).elf $(BINARY).bin`

Thanks

Comment: The `@$` is not a single token.  It's two different tokens: `@` followed by `$`.  You could a space between them if that makes it clearer for you... make doesn't care.

Answer (score 3):

The `@` sign in the beginning of the recipe command means "do not echo the command".

The `$(OBJCOPY)` in your recipe command means "substitute here the value of the `OBJCOPY` variable".

For more info about recipe echoing, please refer to https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing